# Should I answer questions with a solution in another programming language?

Tags: discussion

So after some time I really found a question that matches mine

[Clustering with some cluster centers fixed/known](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14051/clustering-with-some-cluster-centers-fixed-known)

except it's asking in R and the only answer is not really satisfying for me. By now I came to terms that I will have to implement an algorithm myself, one that would fit the question heading. So my question is, should I post it as an answer or rather leave it be? Or do you think I may should ask my own question in my programming language, hope that a solution comes along and if not post my solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can answer the existing question. It's not really important what language you use to illustrate the algorithm; but explain it in English first, & then try to make the code as clear as you can (through comments, informative variable names, &c.) for people who aren't fluent in that language (which is much the same thing as making it as clear as you can for people who are fluent).